# Angular4 error with object inside html

Tags: angular

I have a problem with my syntax.

i want to use this symbol at my inline object

```
object?.something
```

but i don't know how to do this with objects that have white space in their name, like:

```
object?[some thing] // this is wrong
```

Comment: can't see how thats a duplicate? i want to get the object variable once it's not undefined anymore. Want to know what the inline syntax is for this action when the key has white space in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this :

```
(object || {})['some thing']
```

Comment: I think it should be `(object || {})['some thing']` (with quotes)

Comment: ofcourse hehe, thank you! i use it like (object) ? object : 0. i'll accept your awnser